# Changing file's details tab(when right click) using the IShellDispatch interface?

Tags: c++, windows, shell, com, windows-shell

As the title says, is it possible, by using the IShellDispatch interface to change some of the fields shown in the details tab when we right click on a certain file and then choose the properties option?

Thanks!

Comment: Why limit yourself to what IShellDispatch can do?

Comment: @ShengJiang蒋晟 Thanks for your response, to sum up, i need to modify Mpeg4 metadata tag programmatically. this means, once im done flushing all content into the media file, i would like to modify its headers(Title, sub-title, aurthor and so on..)
i dont limit my self using only IShellDispatch, the only limition i've got is that in my stdafx.h my minimum OS to be used is win2000, so using the SHGetPropertyStoreFromParsingName is out of the question.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Vista/7 use the Shell property store to update the details fields in the shell property page. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/benkaras/archive/2006/11/21/writing-properties-9-summary.aspx for an example.

For 2000/XP you need to use compound file APIs as the metadata is stored in NTFS alternative stream or the file itself, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379964.aspx

Comment: Thanks alot, for some reasons, i've encountered several problems with the Compound files structure, therefore, we're going to allow description changing only from Vista+(IPropertyStore) by dynamiclly linking the Shell32.DLL and retreiving the SH... function adress..
Thanks alot!